# trouble with linked list values C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to teach myself c++. to do so I made a challenge for myself to write a prime finder app. I've succeeded once in python (to learn python) with a less efficient algorithm. I'm using a doubly linked list to store the primes. currently I'm just trying to run this in a single thread but I made it doubly linked so I could multithread it later on.

anyway, TL;DR the debugger is showing the program getting stuck trying to assign a value to the start link's prm int in the Prime constructor I've done a bunch of searching but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. (also note the bings are debug messages)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;

struct PLink{
    int prm;
    PLink *next;
    PLink *prev;
};   

class Prime{



    public:
        PLink *start, *end;

        Prime(){
            start -> prm = 2;
            end -> prm = 3;
            start->next = end;
            end->next = NULL;
            start->prev = NULL;
            end->prev = start;            
            addToEnd(5);
            cout <<"cbing" << endl;
        }
        void insert(int val){

        }     
        void addToEnd(int val){//adds a new prime to the end of the    list
            PLink *tmp = new PLink;
            tmp->prm = val;
            tmp->prev = end;
            end->next = tmp;
            tmp->next = NULL;
            tmp = end;
            cout << tmp->prm << endl;
            cout << "addbing" << endl;
        }   
        bool comp(int pot){ //compares the potential prime against known primes via modulo
            int lim = sqrt(pot);
            PLink * current = start;
            bool check = false;
            cout<<"bing " << pot << endl;
            while (current->prm < lim && check == false){
                if (pot%current->prm == 0) {
                    check = true;}
                current = current->next;                                                
            }
            return check; //false means its prime true means its not
        }

};

int main()
{
    Prime primeList;
    int cap = 10000;
    int beg = 5;
    int count = 3;
    bool toggle = false;
    bool check = false;
    cout << "2 \n3 \n5" << endl;
    while(count < cap){
        beg += 2;
        cout << "bing" << endl;
        if (toggle){
            beg += 2;}
        toggle = !toggle;
        check = primeList.comp(beg);
        if (check == false){
            primeList.addToEnd(beg);
            count++;   
            cout << "bing2" << endl;         
        }
    }    
};
```

Comment: Why not just use the STL `std::list` and then you could get on with what your program is trying to do -- find primes.

Comment: `start -> prm = 2; end -> prm = 3; start->next = end;`  You are accessing an uninitialized pointer in the constructor.   This will not work.

Comment: And if you must write your own Linked List, do not couple it with the prime searcher. You wind up having to debug two algorithms at the same time. Not fun.

Comment: I suggest you write your own, working, linked list first.  You're missing a lot of fundamentals concerning proper C++ memory management and pointers.  Otherwise if your goal is to just get a prime finder working, then as my first comment suggested, ditch the pointers and use what the language library provides as a doubly linked list, and that is `std::list`.

Comment: thank you for such a fast reply like I said I'm just learning c++ I'm decently versed in C# and Java so really I chose this challenge because I could learn pointers from it and try to learn c++ memory management. I also had no Idea std::list was a thing. so how do a I properly initialize my pointers?

Comment: @Urmamasllama -- Pointers have to point somewhere valid first before you can apply `->` to them.  You have to create `PLink` objects first and then point the pointers to them.  There are several ways of creating the object, `new PLink`, etc.  This is not that trivial if you're doing this on your own.  You need to get a good book on C++, and I even suggest finding a well-coded, working, and understandable linked list class so that you can study how it is put together.  All I can say is that I have *never* seen a beginner get a linked list C++ class correct on their own without horrible flaws.

Comment: @Urmamasllama [Here is std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;
using std::cout;
```

the second `using std::cout;` is redundant, you can read some documents about C++ name visibility, like this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm

```
Prime(){
    start -> prm = 2;
    end -> prm = 3;
    start->next = end;
    end->next = NULL;
    start->prev = NULL;
    end->prev = start;            
    addToEnd(5);
    cout <<"cbing" << endl;
}
```

Note: when you declare a pointer like `PLink *start, *end;` C++ complier(say 'gcc' or clang) only allocate memory to store that pointer, but not allocate memory to store what your pointer is pointed(here it means your `PLink` object).

So, you should allocate memory for your `PLink` object pointed by these two pointers: `PLink *start, *end;`, that is to say, you have to change the above code to:

```
Prime(){
    start = new PLink(); // use the default constructor generated by C++ complier since you haven't declared one in struct PLink
    end = new PLink()
    start -> prm = 2;
    end -> prm = 3;
    start->next = end;
    end->next = NULL;
    start->prev = NULL;
    end->prev = start;            
    addToEnd(5);
    cout <<"cbing" << endl;
}
```

Well, in order not to cause memory leak and double free the same pointer, you should carefully manipulate the object you created.